# angular app suddenly stopped working on chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

weirdest thing just happened. My angular app was working fine until last night. This morning, when I run it, it doesn't work on Chrome. I haven't modified anything to the code, and I see no errors on the developer console. What makes it even more weird is, the app works just fine all other browsers and even in incognito mode in Chrome. I tried disabling some extensions but that didn't do the trick either. On the surface, what seems to be the problem is that the any paths following the hashtag is not being populated whether I use ui.router or ngroute. Manually typing the paths does not work either. Does anybody have the same problem? What is going on?!

Comment: try clearing browser cache..or just press `Ctrl + R`

Comment: are you using any cdn while loading third party js?

Answer (score 1):

Just clearing cache didn't work. I had to to clear the cookies and plugin data as well. I'm thinking it might be related to recent Auth0 implementation. Will need to look into it so the problem doesn't occur again. For now though, I will close the question.